# Expecting a sample of 1% or 3 in Audit script

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda

I am working on a script that takes a sample from each category in an excel file. The script work, but my results are not as expected--I get a sample of 2 all together. I want the script to take a 1, 3, or 5% from every category, unless there are a limited number of items in the category; in which case, I want a sample of 2. I have reproduced the code below--sorry for the big block of text, I just thought it would helpful to see the whole code. Any help to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

```
#imports
import pandas as pd

#read file
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\***\Desktop\***.xlsx")

#check for certain condition (Y)
df2 = df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')]
print(len(df2))


#unique categories and subcategories
categories = df2['Category'].unique()
subcategories = df2['Subcategory'].unique()

#check for empty subcategories
subcategory = df2['Subcategory'].isnull().all()

#taking a sample based on whether subcategory is empty and the number of y-tracked items 
if subcategory == True:
    def sample_per(df2):
        if len(df2) >= 1500:
            for category in categories: 
                return df2.loc[(df2["Category"] == category)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if 
                x.size*0.01 < 2 else x.sample(frac=0.01))
       elif len(df2) < 15000 and len(df2) > 10000:
            for category in categories: 
                return df2.loc[(df2["Category"] == category)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if 
                x.size*0.03 < 2 else x.sample(frac=0.03))
       else:
            for category in categories: 
                return df2.loc[(df2["Category"] == category)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if 
                x.size*0.05 < 2 else x.sample(frac=0.05))
else:
     def sample_per(df2):
        if len(df2) >= 1500:
            for subcategory in subcategories: 
                return df2.loc[(df2["Subcategory"] == subcategory)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if 
                x.size*0.01 < 2 else x.sample(frac=0.01))
        elif len(df2) < 15000 and len(df2) > 10000:
            for subcategory in categories: 
                return df2.loc[(df2["Subcategory"] == subcategory)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if 
                x.size*0.03 < 2 else x.sample(frac=0.03))
        else:
            for subcategory in subcategories: 
                return df2.loc[(df2["Subcategory"] == subcategory)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if 
                x.size*0.05 < 2 else x.sample(frac=0.05))

    #result of sample_per function
    final = sample_per(df2)
```

The spacing looks off because the lines are long--indentation is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two problems in the code you posted. First, in a function, `return` will stop evaluation of the function as soon as it's hit. This means that you're not going to return a sample for each category, but only sample the first (sub)category and then exit the function entirely. Second, the order of your if conditions means that the middle condition can never be triggered and both small *and* large dataframes (<1500 or >=15000 rows) will both be treated with that third condition.

Here's a function that I think should do what you want. First, I do the category/subcategory test to determine which column to use (and eliminate a lot of duplicate code as a result) and get the (sub)categories as appropriate. Second, I create an empty dataframe to hold the results. The loop will append the different subsamples to this. Note that this is not a computationally efficient way of doing this, but it shouldn't be an issue as long as your dataframes don't get too huge. Third, I create an internal function to actually do the subsampling. Finally, I rearranged the order of the if/else conditions. By starting with the largest and working down, they're mutually exclusive and exhaustive of all possibilities. Note that the last condition is for if you have <1500 rows. In this case the code will return nothing (or more accurately, the function will return an empty dataframe). Your question doesn't specify how you want to treat that, so for now it just has `pass` as a placeholder.

```
def sample_per(df):
    # Conditionally set column name and categories variable
    if df['Subcategory'].isnull().all():
        col_name = 'Subcategory'
    else:
        col_name = 'Category'

    # Get unique (sub)categories
    categories = df[col_name].unique()

    # Create an empty dataframe to store results
    sample_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Create an internal function to do the sampling
    def subsample(df, col_name, cat, frac):
        return df.loc[(df[col_name] == cat)].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if x.size*frac < 2 else x.sample(frac=frac))

    if df.shape[0] >= 15000:
        for cat in categories:
            sample_df = sample_df.append(subsample(df, col_name, cat, 0.05))
    elif df.shape[0] >= 10000:
        for cat in categories:
            sample_df = sample_df.append(subsample(df, col_name, cat, 0.03))
    elif df.shape[0] >= 1500:
        for cat in categories:
            sample_df = sample_df.append(subsample(df, col_name, cat, 0.01))
    else:
        pass

    # Return the sampled dataframe
    return sample_df

# result of sample_per function
final = sample_per(df2)
```

Of course you could also do all of this using `groupby`:

```
def simple_sample(df):
    # Conditionally set column name
    if df['Subcategory'].isnull().all():
        col_name = 'Subcategory'
    else:
        col_name = 'Category'

    def subsample(df, col_name, frac):
        return df.groupby(col_name).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2) if x.size*frac < 2 else x.sample(frac=frac))

    if df.shape[0] >= 15000:
        return subsample(df, col_name, 0.05)
    elif df.shape[0] >= 10000:
        return subsample(df, col_name, 0.03)
    elif df.shape[0] >= 1500:
        return subsample(df, col_name, 0.01)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help!